# Oracle Select to show distinct results

Tags: oracle

I would like to show the distinct occurrence of certain column, Numbering the different brands of cars something like this:

```
Brand              Car     DistinctBrand
Honda              Civic               1
Honda              CRV                 1
Ford               Edge                2
GM                 Blazer              3
GM                 Bolt                3
Fiat               50                  4
Fiat               500                 4
Fiat               Trekking            4
```

I would like to know the number of brands I have on result set as a column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `DENSE_RANK` analytic function:

```sql
SELECT brand,
       car,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY brand) AS distinct_brands
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (Brand, Car) AS
SELECT 'Honda', 'Civic'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Honda', 'CRV'      FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Ford',  'Edge'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GM',    'Blazer'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GM',    'Bolt'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Fiat',  '50'       FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Fiat',  '500'      FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Fiat',  'Trekking' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| BRAND | CAR | DISTINCT_BRANDS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Fiat | 500 | 1 |
| Fiat | 50 | 1 |
| Fiat | Trekking | 1 |
| Ford | Edge | 2 |
| GM | Bolt | 3 |
| GM | Blazer | 3 |
| Honda | Civic | 4 |
| Honda | CRV | 4 |

*(With the brands in alphabetical order)*

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZJaVPRj-)

Comment: DENSE_RANK worked fine. Thank you.